# Pyramid match kernel , partitioning the feature space

Tags: computer-vision, histogram

I am trying to implement the pyramid match kernel , and now I am stuck in a point .
I understand i need to partition the feature space into increasing larger bins , so that at higher levels multiple points[feature vectors] will map to a single bin. What I cant seem to figure out is what is how to partition a feature space. I understood the case where the feature vectors are 1 or 2 dimensional , but how to  partition a d dimensional feature space. 
I understand the question is vague , But I just dont know where else to ask.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

i may be wrong here, but I guess the intuition is to quantize the feature space. So, you could basically do bag of words with different code book sizes (128,64,32...) and use their kernel to compute similarity between 2 images.

Comment: well , I am working on the algorithm , I think I have it figured , will post back once I have it working . The idea is to partition the feature space into bins from size one to a size that can fit the largest and the smallest d dimensional feature vector